# Obtaining Maclaurin series of different functions from simpler ones

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I've noticed that it's tedious or time consuming to calculate Maclaurin series of some functions like  $e^{x^{2}}$ or $\sin(1/x)$ directly.
But the use of the simple expansion of $e^{x}$ or $\sin(x)$ and substitution of $x^{2}$ or $\frac{1}{x}$  respectively for $x$ would yield the desired results. I know that this works for all functions however I'm looking for a justification or theory behind this.

Comment: It's just a matter of composing two functions

Comment: The Taylor series is the unique power series of a function, so once you get a valid power series, it must be the Taylor series.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Notice that the substitution of $1/x$ for $x$ does not yield a Taylor series, it only works with polynomial substitutions.

Comment: The only problem that might happen with substitution is that the values of the substituted function  dord not live within the interval of convergence. Fortunately, the radius of convergence for the exponential and trigonometric /hyperbolic functions  is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a convergent entire series

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k,$$

you can formally substitute a function for $x$ and write

$$f(g(t))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kg^k(t),$$

which is valid as long as $g(t)$ lies in the domain of convergence of $f$. In particular,

$$f(t^m)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^{km}.$$

You can also substitute a polynomial $p(t)$, and you still get an entire series. Beware anyway that if you regroup the terms, you may need absolute convergence to hold.

Now the entire series can be seen as a Taylor development, and by uniqueness of this development,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kp^k(t)$$ is the Taylor development of $f(p(t))$.